# Azure SignalR Service is Logging ConnectionIsInvalidOnJoiningGroup

Tags: azure, signalr

I am working on a .NET Core Web API and switching our SignalR functionality to use Azure SignalR Service. I have a hub that attempts to add a connection to a group similar to this:

```
public async Task Subscribe(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}
```

When I call the hub method from Postman, it is not adding the connection to the group and from the Live Trace Tool it is logging a "ConnectionIsInvalidOnJoiningGroup" event with the message: *"Connection NThbLZQ9f6g3XCj1e987NsM is invalid when add it to group Org1 via message [1010050182311292541]."*

Any ideas on why it's not able to add the connection to a group?

Comment: I am having a similar issuer issue trying to migrate our existing .Net 6 Web Api SignalR implementation to use Azure SignalR service. Everything was working fine with our standalone SignalR implementation until we introduced Azure Front Door in front of our app service which broke web sockets. So now we decided to use Azure SignalR Service to help restore web sockets to our Angular front-end application. Any suggestions or ideas how to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve the issue by adding our App Service to the "**SignalR Rest API Owner**" role.

These are the steps I had to take to connect via Postman:

1. Create new Http Request
2. Set method to POST
3. Add "Authorization" header with Bearer token.
4. Send POST to https://path/to/my/hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1
5. Copy "url" value from response
6. Create new WebSocket Request
7. Set Url type to Raw
8. Paste URL from step 5 and replace "https" with "wss"
9. Add "access_token" param and set to "accessToken" value from POST response.
10. Connect
11. Send message to set protocol:
    {"protocol":"json","version":1}
12. Send message to invoke my hub method.
    {"target":"MyHubMethod","arguments":["arg1", "arg2"],"invocationId":"0","type":1}

A simpler way to test is to use this web client: https://gourav-d.github.io/SignalR-Web-Client/dist/